# Magento 2 - How can I define constants or variables once and reuse them in a custom module?

Tags: magento2, module, custom, variables

I have a few constants that I'd like to define once and reuse many times within various files throughout my custom module.  For example, I write log entries to a custom file.  I'd like to add its pre-defined path in a central location and reference it from controllers, models, helpers, console commands, etc.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways like:

> a) helper class

1) Declare the helper class and define your constants and variables in it.

2) Inject it as a dependency in all your classes.

3) Now the constants and variables will be available in all your classes.

> b) Config.xml

1) Declare your constants and variables in it.

2) You can access its values using ScopeConfigInterface.

3) If you don't know how, leave your comment and I will update my answer.

> c)  Class with constants and static varibles

1) Declare a Class with constants and static varibles

2) Now you can access the constants and variables without instantiating the class.

Choose as per your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Pick a PHP class in your module and define the constant in there using `const` keyword. For example `const LOG_FILE = 'file/path';`.

You can access it from anywhere like `\Class\Name::LOG_FILE`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the best way is to create a custom logger class which implements the `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` and define your path in that class (either as a constant or a pre-defined constructor variable).  Then just `use` that class in any place you need it.

```
namespace My\Module\Controller;

use My\Module\Logger\DebugLogInterface;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Test extends Action
{
    protected $debugLogger;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        DebugLogInterface $debugLogger
    ) {
        $this->debugLogger = $debugLogger;
        parent::__construct(Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry);
    }

    public function execute() {
        $this->debugLogger->info('We are here!');
    }
}
```